Unity Netcode How to reparent an object
I am making a multiplayer game using Unity Netcode. When my player object approaches a planet object, I want to parent the player object to the planet so it moves with it. How should I do this please?
Trying to use RPCs, it seems to be difficult to get it to happen when playing as the client. I have no idea how to do it properly and can't find suitable tutorials.

In general physics in networked multi-user experiences is always a big topic ... If you do physics server sided the own client will always have uncanny delays - however for something like your planets the physics can not be handled client sided ...

So are you saying that reparenting to a moving object will never work?

Be careful dual-tagging a question with C and C++ tags.  You're apt to incur the wrath of the denizens of the tags unless your question is about the interoperability of C and C++.  I think you should choose one of the two language tags and delete the other.  Your call on which language you're primarily working in.

I recommend you visit [gamedev.se] before posting there.

You want to attach your player to the planet.  The planet can have multiple containers, such as one for orbiting objects.  Have the planet develop a method where it appends a player or other object to one of its containers; maybe prefer one method per container.

If you want to "move with something", you have to target it; which usually means its center point. You can then rotate inside it; around it; follow it; fly along with it.; stay in front of it; etc.

@Podhakkin I didn't say that ... other games do it .. I'm just saying it is sometimes not very trivial. Networking gameplay is a quite complex topic .. see e.g. here .. for NetCode specific see Physics ... maybe the moment you attach to a planet you would have to do so server sided and then only transmit the user input .. but as said the delay might feel uncanny ..

Some games (e.g. CounterStrike) even do some syncing of local and server side calculations including movement prediction etc - so you would simulate the physics both locally and remote and then in intervals synchronize both (probably giving the server side more weight to make it fair to everyone)

@GerrySchmitz how would one "target" a GameObject in Unity code?

@ThomasMatthews what function would attach one GameObject to another?

In C++, I would use a std::vector or std::list to contain pointers to objects.  This is how attachment would work.  I don't know of any functions that perform attaching.

@PodHakkin I maintain my own collections (Dictionaries) based on need. If one object starts firing on another (for example), a "relationship" is created until one destroys the other or one is dispersed. This might develop into a one to many. This is maintained via a dictionary of "who's firing on who".
